# XML Editor with syntax check in JavaFX

Tags: xml, javafx, syntax-highlighting, syntax-checking, xml-editor

I'm looking for a way to build a XML editor with JavaFX, which checks the syntax and displays errors and also has syntax highlighting. Does anyone has an idea how to do that? Are there already components which I can use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can help but you can check [Scene Builder source code](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder) and [e(fx)clipse source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/). They might contain some relevant code samples for you